# Control Value Accessor shifting focus

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
import { Component, Input, forwardRef, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'formatted-currency-input',
  templateUrl: '../views/formattedCurrencyInput.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormattedCurrencyInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  styles: ['.formatted-input {text-align: right; height: 100%; border: none; padding-right: 5px;}']
})

export class FormattedCurrencyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  
  @Input()
  private _stringValue: string;

  //private _stringValue: string;

  @Input()
  private _numberValue: number;
  
  textVisible: boolean = false;

  get numberValue() {
    return this._numberValue;
  }

  set numberValue(val: number) {
    this._numberValue = val;
    this.propagateChange(this._numberValue);
  }

  get stringValue() {
    return this._stringValue;
  }

  set stringValue(val: string) {
    this._stringValue = val;
    this.propagateChange(this._stringValue);
  }

  setValue(e: any) {
    let val = e.target.value;
    this._numberValue = parseInt(val);
    this.convertToString(this._numberValue);
    this.propagateChange(this._stringValue);
  }

  toggleActive() {
    this.textVisible = !this.textVisible;
    //console.log(input);
    //input.focus();
  }

  convertToString(num: any) {
    this._stringValue = parseFloat(num).toLocaleString();
  }

  /*
   * Writes a new value from the form model into the view
   * or (if needed) Dom property
   */
  writeValue(obj: any) {
    // Only set the value when it is not undefined
    if (obj !== undefined) {
      this.convertToString(obj);
    }
  }

  propagateChange = (_: any) => {};

  /*
   * Method that registers a handler that should be called when
   * something in the view has changed. It gets a function (propagateChange)
   * that tells other forn directives and form controls to update
   * their values
   */
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  /*
   * Similar to registerOnChage(), this registers a handler
   * specifically for when a control receives a touch event
   */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    console.log('onTouched()');
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {

  }

}
```

```html
<input class="formatted-input" [hidden]="textVisible" type="text" (focus)="toggleActive()" value="{{_stringValue}}"/>
<input class="formatted-input" [hidden]="!textVisible" type="number" (change)="setValue($event)" (blur)="toggleActive()"/>
```

Okay, I have a bit of a weird one. I have built a custom form control for a project at work that basically contains two inputs. One of them is a number input and his hidden until a user click on the input. The other is a text input and is used to display the number with commas. Everything works fine except that when a user clicks into the component they have to click twice to get the number input to gain focus. How can I make this happen and please let me know if I can clarify this issue as I know this is a strange situation[image]

Comment: Please post actual code and not screenshots. You'll also want to add your component code.

Comment: blur is the exact opposite of getting focus

Comment: Yes, I am using blur because I only want that function to run when the user tabs away from the input

Comment: You can try using @ ViewChildren('formated-input') inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>; and, in ngAfterViewInit() subscribe to changes. then focus in the only element

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtxfbe). That demo uses a simplified version of the code, without the `ControlValueAccessor` implementation. You will notice that I applied a weird formatting to `stringValue` to make it clear which input field is active, and that I reversed the meaning of `textVisible` in the markup.

Here are the main changes:

- Binding the `value` property of the number input to `numberValue`
- Defining a template reference variable `#numberInput` on the number input
- Passing that variable to a `focusInput` function in the `(focus)` event handler of the text input
- Calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` before setting the focus on the number input

**Markup**

```
<input [hidden]="!textVisible" type="text" value="{{stringValue}}"
       (focus)="toggleActive(); focusInput(numberInput)"/>

<input #numberInput [hidden]="textVisible" type="number" [value]="numberValue" 
       (change)="setValue($event)" (blur)="toggleActive()"/>
```

**Code (simplified version)**

```
textVisible = true;
numberValue = 7248;

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

toggleActive() {
  this.textVisible = !this.textVisible;
}

get stringValue(): string {
  return this.numberValue.toLocaleString();
}

setValue(event: Event) {
  this.numberValue = parseInt((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value, 10);
}

focusInput(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  this.cd.detectChanges();
  input.focus();
}
```